# Android Picasso remove entry from cache

Tags: android, picasso

Does anyone know of a way to remove entries from Picasso default Cache / invalidate?

I went over their api (Also Picasso Cache class ) and couldn't find any way of doing it. I'm not interested in `skipMemoryCache` because most of the time the image  Should be loaded from the cache.

Thanks!

Roy

Comment: For whoever voted this question down, can you please explain why? this question is clear, i've researched before and seen that there are no answers in stackoverflow, i've went over Picasso api and still couldn't find an answer. i've also clarified which answers i'm not looking for so i really wanna know why you voted it down?

Comment: There is no way to control the cache yet. You could supply your own in the Picasso builder and hold to the reference. In a future version we are planning on introducing a cache control mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's possible to invalidate cache using [`Picasso.invalidate()`](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#invalidate-android.net.Uri-).

Usage examples:

```
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(uri);
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(pathString);
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(file);
```